# How to add a column inside a for loop in Pandas without it breaking

Tags: python, pandas, polygon.io

I have the following code:

```
from polygon import RESTClient
key = ''
all_tickers = [
    # {'ticker': 'A', 'name': 'Agilent Technologies Inc.', 'market': 'stocks', 'locale': 'us', 'primary_exchange': 'XNYS', 'type': 'CS', 'active': True, 'currency_name': 'usd', 'cik': '0001090872', 'composite_figi': 'BBG000C2V3D6', 'share_class_figi': 'BBG001SCTQY4', 'last_updated_utc': '2022-03-16T00:00:00Z'}, {'ticker': 'AA', 'name': 'Alcoa Corporation', 'market': 'stocks', 'locale': 'us', 'primary_exchange': 'XNYS', 'type': 'CS', 'active': True, 'currency_name': 'usd', 'cik': '0001675149', 'composite_figi': 'BBG00B3T3HD3', 'share_class_figi': 'BBG00B3T3HF1', 'last_updated_utc': '2022-03-16T00:00:00Z'}
    {
    "ticker": "ATNI",
    "name": "ATN International, Inc",
    "market": "stocks",
    "locale": "us",
    "primary_exchange": "XNAS",
    "type": "CS",
    "active": True,
    "currency_name": "usd",
    "cik": "0000879585",
    "composite_figi": "BBG000F8RCH1",
    "share_class_figi": "BBG001S9SMF2",
    "last_updated_utc": "2022-03-27T00:00:00Z"
  }, {
    "ticker": "ATNM",
    "name": "Actinium Pharmaceuticals, Inc",
    "market": "stocks",
    "locale": "us",
    "primary_exchange": "XASE",
    "type": "CS",
    "active": True,
    "currency_name": "usd",
    "cik": "0001388320",
    "composite_figi": "BBG000RQZ245",
    "share_class_figi": "BBG001SV3L17",
    "last_updated_utc": "2022-03-27T00:00:00Z"
  }
    ]
```

I then try to loop through the tickers and append them to a dataframe while adding the ticker as a column to each of the lists:

```
with RESTClient(key) as client:
    from_ = "2020-01-09"
    to = "2021-01-10"
    df_list = []
    
    for i in all_tickers:
        ticker =  i['ticker']
        r = client.stocks_equities_aggregates(ticker, 1, "day", from_, to, unadjusted=False)
    
        print(f"Daily aggregates for {r.ticker} between {from_} and {to}.")

        try:
            df = pd.DataFrame(r.results)
            df['ticker'] = ticker
            df_list.append(df)

        except:
            print('nothing')
    combined_df = pd.concat(df_list,ignore_index=True)
    print(combined_df, 'comb')
```

But here's the result I get:

```
Daily aggregates for ATNI between 2020-01-09 and 2021-01-10.
Daily aggregates for ATNM between 2020-01-09 and 2021-01-10.
            v       vw      o      c        h      l              t     n  \
0     58871.0  57.2358  57.22  56.99  57.7600  56.81  1578546000000  1364   
1     72964.0  56.3568  57.10  55.69  57.2400  55.59  1578632400000  1499   
2     33738.0  55.9086  55.70  56.10  56.2000  55.45  1578891600000   950   
3     98525.0  55.8561  55.86  55.97  56.2400  55.50  1578978000000  1777   
4     31869.0  56.0751  55.89  55.85  56.4400  55.69  1579064400000   940   
..        ...      ...    ...    ...      ...    ...            ...   ...   
501  895346.0   8.0596   7.99   7.86   8.3560   7.78  1609736400000  4429   
502  642829.0   8.2878   8.05   8.57   8.6000   7.89  1609822800000  3249   
503  666115.0   8.1616   8.55   8.02   8.5800   7.95  1609909200000  3778   
504  700868.0   8.2889   8.03   8.58   8.5900   8.02  1609995600000  2973   
505  376746.0   8.3241   8.42   8.24   8.5511   8.12  1610082000000  3052   

    ticker  
0     ATNI  
1     ATNI  
2     ATNI  
3     ATNI  
4     ATNI  
..     ...  
501   ATNM  
502   ATNM  
503   ATNM  
504   ATNM  
505   ATNM  

[506 rows x 9 columns] comb
```

If I remove the 'df['ticker'] = ticker' line it works as expected, giving me both lists joined together, like so:

```
Daily aggregates for ATNI between 2020-01-09 and 2021-01-10.
Daily aggregates for ATNM between 2020-01-09 and 2021-01-10.
            v       vw      o      c        h      l              t     n
0     58871.0  57.2358  57.22  56.99  57.7600  56.81  1578546000000  1364
1     72964.0  56.3568  57.10  55.69  57.2400  55.59  1578632400000  1499
2     33738.0  55.9086  55.70  56.10  56.2000  55.45  1578891600000   950
3     98525.0  55.8561  55.86  55.97  56.2400  55.50  1578978000000  1777
4     31869.0  56.0751  55.89  55.85  56.4400  55.69  1579064400000   940
..        ...      ...    ...    ...      ...    ...            ...   ...
501  895346.0   8.0596   7.99   7.86   8.3560   7.78  1609736400000  4429
502  642829.0   8.2878   8.05   8.57   8.6000   7.89  1609822800000  3249
503  666115.0   8.1616   8.55   8.02   8.5800   7.95  1609909200000  3778
504  700868.0   8.2889   8.03   8.58   8.5900   8.02  1609995600000  2973
505  376746.0   8.3241   8.42   8.24   8.5511   8.12  1610082000000  3052
```

How do I join both the lists together and include the ticker symbol as a column, without breaking the dataframe?

How I need the DF to look:

```
            v       vw      o      c        h      l              t  n     ticker 
0     58871.0  57.2358  57.22  56.99  57.7600  56.81  1578546000000  4424  ATNI
...
250  895346.0   8.0596   7.99   7.86   8.3560   7.78  1609736400000  4429  ATNM
...
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, there is no problem. Take a close look again at the first dataframe. There is a "\" in the output, indicating that the output continues! It is not a break or anything else, but an indiacator for the rest of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amirhossein, I will update the OP with how I expect the DF to look so it makes more sense

Comment: Glad to help. I keep following the question and would answer/comment if there was anything I could help you with.

Comment: I've updated the OP to show what I'm after

Comment: I still have the same comment. I guess you are using IDE, and not Jupyter lab nor Colab notebooks. If you used these, which are used for interactive data science and scientific programming,  you would see the dataframe you are expecting is as the same dataframe you shown in the very first cell. Please conside using one of these two. If you do, please let me know what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: Let me add something else to make sure you are clear on what's going on. The IDE's outputs, generally speaking, are not user-friendly. So, what you see the first cell in your dataframe, is the result of the line with `print(combined_df, 'comb')`. Usually, pandas dataframe are not meant to be printed out, rather they are usually *displayed* in a user-friendly way. These two above-mentioneds, help you to work with the dataframes more efficiently and have better output. So, if you used `display` function (`display(combined_df)`) instead of print, you would see your desired(expected) output.

Comment: Ah you legend! Thanks Amirhossein